# Configuring QueryDSL for Spring Data and MongoDB with Gradle

Tags: mongodb, gradle, querydsl

I guess I haven't configured the repositories properly, but there are other problems too with the following build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.7"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'

jar {
    baseName = 'aydin'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }

}

querydsl {
    springDataMongo = true
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")

    compile group: "de.flapdoodle.embed", name: "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo", version: "1.50.3"

    compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.3"
    compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.6.3:jpa" // Magic happens here
    compile "com.querydsl.apt:querydsl-mongodb:4.0.9"

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14'
}
```

Which gives me:

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.7.
>        Required by:
>   ...
>   Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.7.
>   Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/gradle/plugin/com/ewerk/gradle/plugins/querydsl-plugin/1.0.7/querydsl-plugin-1.0.7.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/gradle/plugin/com/ewerk/gradle/plugins/querydsl-plugin/1.0.7/querydsl-plugin-1.0.7.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Comment: Possibly you need to include the repo having the querydsl plugin?

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you need to include the repo having the querydsl plugin?

```
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
```