# Querydsl mongodb gradle springboot issue

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle, spring-boot, querydsl

I am trying to use querydsl in my project like it is described here in spring boot documentation,
[springboot-mongodb-look at 5.3.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) so that I can do this,

```
QPerson person = new QPerson("person");
List<Person> result = repository.findAll(person.address.zipCode.eq("C0123"));

Page<Person> page = repository.findAll(person.lastname.contains("a"), 
                                       new PageRequest(0, 2, Direction.ASC, "lastname"));
```

I am using gradle build and mongodb for database.

My problem is, in querydsl documentation, only the maven integration is provided. [querydsl document link](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s07.html)
i.e

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And now, configure the Maven APT plugin which generates the query types used by Querydsl:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
              <processor>com.querydsl.apt.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Can this be integrated using gradle? If yes, please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [querydsl-with-gradle-and-idea](http://bsideup.blogspot.ca/2015/04/querydsl-with-gradle-and-idea.html) and [Configuring QueryDSL for Spring Data and MongoDB with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815658/configuring-querydsl-for-spring-data-and-mongodb-with-gradle):

They use:

```
compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.6.3:jpa"
compile "com.querydsl.apt:querydsl-mongodb:4.0.9"
```

and [github corneil's spring-data-demo](https://github.com/corneil/spring-data-demo/blob/master/spring-data-querydsl-demo/build.gradle)'s complete example, detailed here: [QueryDSL for Mongo with Spring and gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383198/641627)

Answer (score 0):

For me helped this article [add Querydslsupport](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/003_tip_add_querydsl_support.html)

Add to your gradle file next:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.9"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "$buildDir/generated/source/app/main"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.4"
    compileOnly "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4"
}

querydsl {
    springDataMongo = true
    querydslSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/source/app/main"
}
```

After that you should add `@Document` annotation to your entity class and just build. You'll see generated Q files under folder specified in querydslSourcesDir.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me with QueryDSL MongoDB 4.4.0 and Gradle 7.

1. Add the following dependencies to your build.gradle file.

   ```
   implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.4.0"
   annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.4.0:general", "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
   ```

   Note: We need `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` in there so that the APT processor can understand the @NotNull etc. in your domain classes.
2. Annotate your domain classes with `@QueryEntity` annotation from `com.querydsl.core.annotations` package (from the first dependency above).

Let Gradle to it's magic and you will see the QClasses .